# Firebase Error: Missing or insufficient permissions only when ran from device

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Trying to update a document within my React Native app works fine when I run from the simulator, but fails with error: "Missing or insufficient permissions" when I run from an actual device. I've made sure I'm logged in.

example code that would raise the error:

```
listing.doc.ref.update({
   quantityAvailable: qty
});
//called from an authenticated user who is the author of the listing. 
//So the request.auth.uid is equal to the listing.user.id
```

The pertinent database rules are as follows:

```
match /listings/{document=**} {
  allow read;
  allow create: if isSignedIn();
  allow update: if isOwner();
}

...

function existingData() {
  return resource.data
}

function incomingData() {
  return request.resource.data
}

function currentUser() {
  return request.auth
}

function isSignedIn() {
  return request.auth != null;
}

function isOwner() {
  return request.auth.uid == existingData().user.id;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that raises the error.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, good point, I have edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: You can add parameters to your isOwner function like this
`isOwner(userId)` so the condition to your function isOwner will be like this
`request.auth.uid === userId` then
replace the default wildcard `{document=**}` with `{userId}`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by switching to the react-native-firebase library instead of the regular node.js Firebase library.  Turns out it's not a permission problem, my permissions are fine, it was a networking issue with react native and the node.js firebase library.